# Why arrow function is not passing arguments?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, rxjs, arrow-functions

I'm using angular w/ rxjs to observe user events on the interface. However, I'm having this really simple problem with passing arguments to a method in an arrow function. Here is the problem:

**This is not working**: searchterm is not being passed to this.searchFacilities

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.searchTerm$.subscribe(searchterm => this.searchFacilities);/**Not working here**/
}

searchFacilities(term: string){
  console.log(term);
  this.facilityservice.searchFacilities(term)
    .subscribe(results => this.facilityList = results);
}
```

**But this works:**

```
this.searchTerm$.subscribe(searchterm => { this.searchFacilities(searchterm); })
```

Clearly, I have other solutions that are pretty painless, but I really want to understand why my first approach is not working. Thanks!

Comment: `searchterm => this.searchFacilities` == `function(searchterm) { return this.searchFacilities }` Why should this call `this.searchFacilities(searchterm)`? O.o

Comment: Just do `this.searchTerm$.subscribe(this.searchFacilities);` You leave the arrows out when *referencing* !

Comment: I really doubt that the last snippet does work

Comment: @Bergi - You're right, I have another subject that I"m subscribing to which calls this method as well...and I got mixed up in my testing. Thanks!

Comment: @adeneo - This is actually much cleaner and it makes sense once I stop and think about it.+1

Comment: *"I really want to understand why my first approach is not working."* Because you are not *calling* `this.searchFacilities`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small clarification. The doc says you need to pass a callback to `subscribe()` and that this callback will receive the value(s) emitted by the observable.

We could write it like this:

```ts
const myCallBack = (val) => console.log(val);
Observable.range(0, 3).subscribe(myCallBack);
```

In your case you already have a callback, `this.searchFacilities`.
This means you can simply write:

```ts
this.searchTerm$.subscribe(this.searchFacilities);
```

Just like you can rewrite my original example to:

```ts
// Now `console.log` is the callback!
Observable.range(0, 3).subscribe(console.log);
```

In other words, the problem is not "Why arrow function is not passing arguments". The problem is that you created an arrow function whose body **IS** your callback, instead of just using your callback directly.

The expanded version of your code would look like this:

```ts
const myCallBack = (searchterm) => {
  return this.searchFacilities;
}
```

As you can see, `searchFacilities` is neither invoked nor does it receive the `searchterm` param.

You could have run into the same problem with a NON-ARROW function by writing the following code (although the syntax of arrow functions does make the mistake more likely and insidious):

```ts
const myCallBack = function(searchterm) {
  return this.searchFacilities;
}
```

Comment: I am glad you submitted this answer. I really wanted to understand what was going on, and I believe this answer covers all sides....What really sunk in is this same problem could be created with the ES5 function syntax. Originally, I was under the false impression that an arrow function will automatically pass parameters when only a single function is referenced in the body....which is not true. But now I also understand that subscribe is just looking for a callback to which I already had in `this.searchFacilities`.

Comment: Hey calbear. Thanks for the feedback. Truth be told, I wasn't sure whether I should submit an answer to an already answered question but since S.O. is about sharing knowledge and promoting best practices, I did. :) There are mostly 2 things you need to remember about **the body** of arrow functions: 1) the `this` keyword isn't bound to the function itself as with ES5 functions; 2) when the body only contains ONE instruction/expression, you can omit the `{ ... }` and you get an implicit `return`. Like you said, there's no implicit passing of parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Because the parameter is not passed directly to your function.

Example from [the doc](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/subscribe.md):

```
Rx.Observable.range(0, 3).subscribe(function (x) { console.log(x) });
```

The same example with an arrow function:

```
Rx.Observable.range(0, 3).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Comment: Gotcha, I thought it DID pass parameters directly to my function. Thanks

Comment: *"Because the parameter is not passed directly to your function."* What do you mean by that? The problem with the OPs code is that their are not calling `this.searchFacilities`.

Comment: +1 to Felix's comment. GG's answer (and calbear's question for that matter) make it sound like the problem is arrow function not passing parameters. But the real problem is more of a **logic error** in the original code resulting in `this.searchFacilities` not being called. The more compact solution would be to write `this.searchTerm$.subscribe(this.searchFacilities);` where there is no trace of an arrow function. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're getting a reference to the searchTerm but you're not doing anything with it. You could just do `this.searchTerm$.subscribe(this.searchFacilities)` and the term will be passed into the function.

Answer (score 0):

You **searchFacilities** function is declared in global scope, and then is called inside of ngOnInit as a callback and its context is not anymore global scope, now ***this*** points to ngOnInit element Object. In order to work inside ngOnInit object you need to bind it and then **searchFacilities** be method of ngOnInit and in this way its going to work.